# How to generate vertical PDF using pdfpages in python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I am using `from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages` to generate PDFs containing multiple (sub)plots.

Is there a way to control the orientation (horizontal/vertical) of the resulting pdf? I constantly get horizontal PDF's

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you set the size of your figure using the `set_size_inches` function, the PDF should automatically be the shape you want:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with PdfPages('portrait.pdf') as pdf:
    x = range(10)
    y = [y * 2 for y in x]

    plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel('x axis')
    plt.ylabel('y axis')
    figure = plt.gcf()
    figure.set_size_inches([7,10])
    pdf.savefig(figure)
```

If you change the size to `[10,7]`, you should see the orientation automatically switch.

`savefig` does have an orientation setting, e.g. `orientation='portrait'` but I don't think this will have any effect. You could try it though.

Comment: The `savefig()` documentation has a comment that says, "Currently only supported by the postscript backend." at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
with PdfPages('portrait.pdf') as pdf:
     pdf.savefig(fig, orientation='portrait')
     plt.close()
```

Comment: The `savefig()` documentation has a comment that says, "Currently only supported by the postscript backend." at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html